# Excel, populate time when another cell has data

Tags: microsoft-excel, time, automatic-update

Somebody else asked if there was a way to automatically populate the current date in a cell based on another cell receiving data.
[NOT those exact words, but same thing, I think]

And Somebody showed this code:
= IF ( ISBLANK ( B10 ) , " " , NOW ( ) )

And that worked PERFECTLY for me!
Thank you to that individual!

Now, I'm wanting to know if there's a similar code I could entry to get current time.
[24hr format if that matters]

TIA!

Comment: NOW() returns a date/time.  Just format it as you want.

Comment: I legit don't know how to do any of this. I goggle all this codes.

Comment: In that case, [this may be usefule](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309)